# CodeIgniter adjusting url when passing parameters to controler

Tags: codeigniter, pagination, routes

Ok i have records from database listed in view file, so u can see i wanna pass values to controler via href by update/grab function controler

```
    echo $this->pagination->create_links();
    br().br();

foreach ($query->result() as $q): ?>
     <a href="update/grab/<?php echo $q->id;?>/<?php echo $q->info; ?>"><?php echo $q->info . br()?></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

it works for first page in my pagination, when i am on some other page when i clicked on on record, instead passing parametars to controler when i clicked in keep adding url for example `http://localhost/z/records/users/update/grab/3/update/grab/1/update/grab/1/update/grab/1/trtr`

So error is when i have in url, when i am on second page in pagination

```
http://localhost/z/records/users/2
```

works only when i am on first page

```
http://localhost/z/records
```

is there a way to solve this proble. Will it works if i some how adjust routes??? Need help, please help me its very important

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your link to an absolute URL:

```
 <a href="/z/update/grab/<?php echo $q->id;?>/<?php echo $q->info; ?>">
```

Or adding a correct relative URL base to the header of your pages:

```
<base href="/z/" />
```

Comment: how can i thank you i just add /z/ in front controle you save me hours of work and maybe they will hire me for job

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter routes allow you to do this:

```
$route['post/(:any)/comment/(:any)'] = "posts/comments/$1/$2";
```

Then in the controller, the function inside my posts controller would work like this:

```
public function comments($one, $two) {
     echo $one."-".$two;
}
```

so if you hit the url "/post/111/comment/222" the output would be

111-222